# MySQLi Login system error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, authentication

I've been working on a login system using **PHP** and the **MySQLi** functions, however I've come across an error that I believe is failing to identify the session, I can't figure out the reason as to why it's happening.

Edit: Updated code.

> Login.PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'db/connect.php';
If (Isset($_POST['Login'])) {
    $EM = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']); //Assign directly no need to create the $EM. You can put the whole into your query also
    $PW = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
    $result = $db->query("select * from users where Email='$EM' AND password='$PW'");
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    $_SESSION["UserID"] = $row['UserID'];
    header('location: Account.php');
    exit;
    }
?>
```

> Account.php

```
<?php
require 'db/connect.php';
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION["UserID"])) {
    include 'header.php'; //It contains output so move after session_start();
    echo 'Successfully logged in';
} else {
    header('location: Login.php');
    exit;
}
 ?>
```

Comment: What's the question / issue? Where is `$db` assigned?

Comment: why do you use `session_start()` two times? Anyway, use an `exit;` after `header('location....');`

Comment: @mitkosoft You should not edit the code, you could have fixed the problem with your edit.

Comment: @jeroen, there is nothing new in my edit, just reformatting the code itself.

Comment: @mitkosoft No, you removed the closing php tag, 2 new-lines and the opening php tag. And that before `session_start()` is called by the OP so you might have fixed the actual problem.

Comment: @25thBaam What does `header.php` do, does it output html / anything?

Comment: @jeroen Not yet, but it will output HTML with links in the future.

Comment: So make sure that `session_start();` is called before that.

Comment: Do not include `header.php` if there is output in it. `Header('location...');` wont works too!

Comment: What should I use instead of Header('location...')?

Comment: Not good: `include 'header.php';
?>
<?php` See my answer.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Edited code based on your answer, still getting redirected to Login.PHP

Answer (score 1):

You have output before calling session_start();. This should cause the "header has already been sent"-fatal error.

Remove the empty line in account.php (closing and opening php doesn't make sense anyway, in this snippet)

```
include 'header.php';
?>

<?php
 session_start();
```

Is there some kind of output in the header.php?

Do you get any errormessages? You can display errors by adding following to the top of your code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

edit after knowing what heder.php does: your account.php should start like this

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'db/connect.php';
include 'header.php';
```

Comment: header.php is empty so far, but it's gonna be pure HTML with links, I've added the error display but no errors show up.

Comment: ok, so header.php is going to output stuff. This means it has to be included after calling session_start();

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Based on OP comments.

Here are the finel files. Do not put anything before `session_start()` or `header()` functions, there should be nothing output in the buffer before these functions.

```
session_start();
require 'db/connect.php';
if (Isset($_POST['Login'])) {
    $EM = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']); //Assign directly no need to create the $EM. You can put the whole into your query also
    $PW = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
    $result = $db->query("select * from users where Email='$EM' AND password='$PW'");
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    $_SESSION["UserID"] = $row['UserID'];
    header('location: Account.php');
    exit;
}
```

And the `Account.php`

```
session_start();
require 'db/connect.php';
if (isset($_SESSION["UserID"])) {
    include 'header.php'; //It contains output so move after session_start();
    echo 'Successfully logged in';
} else {
    header('location: Login.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I closed the PHP code at the end because the HTML code with the form comes after it, edited the rest of the code to what you suggested.

Comment: Thats ok, only no need, if no more content after php. It's a good practice to avoid any space, new line (output) after closing tag. What do you get now?

Comment: I still get redirected to Login.PHP, when I know the pass is correct by copying it from the DB.

Comment: I've tried this code but it still sends me to Login.php

Comment: Then, for some reason, `$_SESSION["UserID"]` not filled. echo the query, run in directly the database. Check, if it has result? If yes, it should works.

Comment: and move `session_start()` before `require 'db/connect.php';` in the `Account.php`

Comment: How do I run it directly in the database and check for a result? also I've moved session_Start() before require 'db/connect.php';